# Visual Studio System.Diagnostics.Debug while not running in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to develop an ASP.NET MVC application.

I want to display my own debugging messages. Console.WriteLine() is not available. I learned about System.Diagnostics.Debug, but this only shows my messages when I'm running with the debugger enabled.
Otherwise, I only see the build info from VS.

I don't want to start up the debugger to test out small changes, as it takes longer and slows things down.

What can I do to show my own debug messages, short of writing them to a file on disk and viewing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practise is to use logger frameworks like **[NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)** or **[Elmah](https://elmah.github.io/)** for errors.

But, you can always implement your own logging system and save output to file or DB.

Another option is to use **Tracing** in Asp.net MVC - [more informations](http://syncbite.com/Code/posts/48/tracing-and-loging-in-aspnet-mvc).